# No puedo hacer una relacion de 1 a 1 entre Cama y Paciente

Tags: genexus

Quiero que paciente y cama tenga un relacion de 1 a 1, pero no puedo, algun consejo?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No creo la relación sea directamente entre cama y paciente, en todo caso tendría una tabla intermedia denominada "ingreso" por ejemplo, que almacene el ID del paciente, la cama, el médico que indica el ingreso, el motivo, etc etc y cuántos campos sean necesarios. La tabla cama solo debería recoger el número, habitación si está disponible o no.

Answer (score 1):

Como dice Francisco, no parece que esa relación 1 a 1 sea conceptualmente correcta.
Pero respondiendo a tu pregunta, lo que debes hacer es marcar como clave primaria (en la Transacción Cama) al atributo IdPaciente. Es lo que en jerga Genexus se llaman "Transacciones Paralelas".

Aquí tienes más información: https://training.genexus.com/es/aprendiendo/pdf/transacciones-paralelas-pdf